# Weird SQL query behavior - Issue with SIC code lookup

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an SIC code lookup and I am having a weird issue with my query. I have 6 table names, description, description-2, description-3. and two-digit-sic, four-digit-sic, and six-digit-sic and I am getting unexpected results.

If I search for an item in any of the description tables (example: agriculture) it will return the correct queries. and it will display as it should. As well as if I only search for a two-digit-sic.  (example: 01)

However if I try and search via six-digit-sic or four-digit-sic It will not display the records.

A weird thing is when I search for the correct six-digit-sic it will say it found records but just not display them. if you put in an incorrect sic code it will just say no records found. example of working six-digit-sic (011198) non-working SIC (112112)

I am truly at a loss as to why this is happening.

this is live here: http://mainstaycomputing.com/client/prospects/list-brokers-resources/sic-code-search/

```
<?php

get_header();

?>



<div id="main-content" style = 'position: relative'>

    <div class = 'wrapper'> 

    <h1 class="entry-title main_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


    <div class = 'sic-text'>
        <p> SIC codes are assigned by the Government and are standard at the 4 digit level.
            The 8 digit codes may be customized by each individual list owner. Because we represent all list
            sources, there may be variance in what the 8 digit codes represent. For greatest accuracy,
            when speaking with one of our List Brokers please supply the sic code # along with a description so
            we can provide as exact a match as possible.To use this search, simply type the Industry you’re
            looking for into the Search By Keyword field. For instance, entering “Dentists” will cause all
            businesses related to dentists listed. <! — If you know the SIC code and want to know the industry
            name, enter the 8 digit code into the Search By Code field. –> </p>

    </div>




    <form action="" method="GET" class = 'sic-search'> 



    <input class = 'sic-search-text' type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for an industry, eg 'Agriculture'"/>


    <input type="submit" value="Search" class = 'sic-search-button'/>
    </form>






<?php 

$search = $_POST['search'];


 $host = "****";
 $user = "****";
 $password = "****";
 $database_name = "****";

 $min_length = 2;
    // you can set minimum length of the sic if you want

    if(strlen($search) >= $min_length && $search != ''){ // if sic length is more or equal minimum length then

       echo "<p id='rowCount'> </p>";

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
// Search from MySQL database table
$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from siccodes where description LIKE ? OR description-2 LIKE ?");
$query->bindValue(2, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// Display search result
         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
                echo "Search found :<br/>";
                echo "<table class='sic-code-table'";   
                echo "<tr><th>description</th><th>two-digit-sic</th><th>description</th><th>four-digit-sic</th><th>description</th><th>six-digit-sic</th></tr>";                
            while ($results = $query->fetch()) { 
                echo "<tr><td>";            
                echo $results['description'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['two-digit-sic'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['description-2'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['four-digit-sic'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['description-3'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['six-digit-sic'];
                echo "</tr>";

            }
                echo "</table>";        
        } else {
              echo "<p style = 'text-align:center; margin-bottom:30px; color: red;'>No results match" . " '" . $search . "' " . "Please try another search term.</p>";
        }
    } else {
        if (!empty($_POST['search'])) {
            echo "<p style = 'text-align:center; margin-bottom:30px; color: red;'> Please search again, '$search' is to short.</p>";
        }
    }


 $host = "****";
 $user = "***";
 $password = "***!";
 $database_name = "*****";

  mysql_connect("****", "****", "****") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
        root - your username
        third is your password

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

    mysql_select_db("****") or die(mysql_error());
    /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */
?>

<?php


    $query = $_GET['search']; 
    // gets value sent over search form


      // if the query is null which it would be when they first enter the page then show all results
      if(empty($_GET['search'])) {
      // $query = '01';

           $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siccodes ") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text `
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

                echo "<table class='sic-code-table'";   
                echo "<tr><th>description</th><th>two-digit-sic</th><th>description</th><th>four-digit-sic</th><th>description</th><th>six-digit-sic</th></tr>";    

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<tr><td>";            
                echo $results['description'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['two-digit-sic'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['description-2'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['four-digit-sic'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['description-3'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['six-digit-sic'];
                echo "</tr>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['description'])
            }
             echo "</table>";
        }
   } // end of displaying all results 
    /* this is the actual search */
    $min_length = 2;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siccodes 
            WHERE (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description-2` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description-3` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`two-digit-sic` = '$query') OR (`four-digit-sic` = '$query') OR (`six-digit-sic` = '$query')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text `
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
                $raw_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($raw_results); 
                $num_rows =  $raw_num_rows - 1;
                echo "<p id='rowCount'> We have retrieved " . " " . $num_rows . " " . " records related to the keyword '$query'</p>";

                echo "<table class='sic-code-table'";   
                echo "<tr><th>description</th><th>two-digit-sic</th><th>description</th><th>four-digit-sic</th><th>description</th><th>six-digit-sic</th></tr>";    

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<tr><td>";            
                echo $results['description'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['two-digit-sic'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['description-2'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['four-digit-sic'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['description-3'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['six-digit-sic'];
                echo "</tr>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['description'])
            }
             echo "</table>";
        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "<p style='text-align:center;color:red;'>No results for '$query' | Please try again";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "<p style='color:orange; text-align:center; '>Minimum length is ".$min_length."</p>";
    }


?>







<!-- creates a form at the bottom of the list if there are more than 100 records -->
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 100) : ?>
<form action="" method="GET" class = 'sic-search'>

    <input class = 'sic-search-text' type="text" name="sic" placeholder="Search for an industry, eg 'Agriculture'"/>


    <input type="submit" value="Search" class = 'sic-search-button'/>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>




    </div> <!-- end of wrapper -->


</script>
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: TLDR :X please truncate lol

Comment: Doesn't having column names with `-` require using backticks? (Edit: you're not doing it for every query).

Comment: Do you store the 2/4/6 digit codes as numbers or strings in the database?

Comment: Any particular reason to be using `PDO` and later the (deprecated) `mysql_*`?

Comment: @neuromatter They are stored as numbers and the data type is varchar for all tables.

Comment: @FirstOne I was having issues with it, time is of the essence unfortunately I think I will learn how to really do it after this project.